# Cannot assign derived raw pointer to base unique_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, smart-pointers, virtual-inheritance

I have some code that looks something this:

```
class Info {
  public:
    virtual bool IsHere() = 0;
    virtual std::wstring GetStr() = 0;
};

class WindowsInfo : public Info {
  public:
    virtual std::wstring GetAnotherStr() = 0;
    bool IsHere() override;
};

class AdvancedWindowsInfo : public WindowsInfo {
  public:
    AdvancedWindowsInfo() {}
    ~AdvancedWindowsInfo() {}

    std::wstring GetAnotherStr() override;
    std::wstring GetStr() override;
};
  
class InfoFactory {
  public:
    static Info* GetInfo();
};
  
class InfoManager {
  public:
    InfoManager();
    //~InfoManager();

    bool IsSomething();

  private:
    std::unique_ptr<Info> info;
};
  
InfoManager::InfoManager() {
  #if WIN
    info = std::make_unique<WindowsInfo>();
  #else  // currently no implementation Linux
    info = nullptr;
  #endif
}
  
bool InfoManager::IsSomething() {
    std::unique_ptr<Info> info = InfoFactory::GetInfo();

    return info && info->IsHere();
}
  
Info* InfoFactory::GetInfo() {
  #if IS_WINDOWS
    return new AdvancedWindowsInfo();
  #else
    return nullptr;
  #endif
}
```

The entire code is too large (and confidential) to post here, but this snippet sums it up pretty well.

Essentially, I have a base class and some derived classes.

I also have a manager that uses a (smart) pointer to that base class.

And a Factory Method that returns the appropriate Derived object (although the signature returns a `Base*`).

Unfortunately, I can't get the the assignment (via the Factory Method) to work. I've tried multiple approaches but nothing works.

I tried using `unique_ptr` and `make_unique<raw pointer>()` --> it doesn't work with derived classes, only base.

I tried using `unique_ptr` and raw pointers --> conversion is not possible.

I tried using raw pointers (although I don't want this) and raw pointers --> it tells me that the destructor is called on the base object which is abstract. How can you call a destructor when you haven't instantiated the object (since it's an abstract class)? The compiler is contradicting itself!

Comment: Can't you have `InfoFactory::GetInfo()` return a `std::unique_ptr<Info>`? That would be more recommended.

Comment: "Doesn't work" and "Can't get it working" are not descriptive. Do you get a compiler error? Does it crash? Do you get unexpected results? If you get an error, what error do you get?

Comment: Also, `std::unique_ptr<Info> info = InfoFactory::GetInfo();` creates a _local_variable info which goes out of scope when the function returns. It leaves the member variable info unaffected. Perhaps what you intended instead was `info.reset( InfoFactory::GetInfo() );`

Comment: "How can you call a destructor when you haven't instantiated the object..." Did you give the real `Info` a `virtual ~Info() = default;` destructor? You didn't give the shown `Info` one. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I did the following:

1. `InfoFactory::GetInfo()` now returns a `std::unique_ptr<Info>`, as indicated by [Galik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3807729/galik)
2. Added `virtual ~Info() = default;` as indicated by [Nathan Pierson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12334309/nathan-pierson)

Now everything seems to be working ok.
For now, I will the question unanswered as I still need to run some tests and double check some things, but basically it seems to be ok.

Thank you to everyone who made positive contibutions!

Answer (score 3):

Let's check the documentation for `std::unique_ptr`'s [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr). The signature of the relevant constructor:

> `explicit unique_ptr( pointer p ) noexcept;`
> (2)

The converting constructor that converts a raw pointer to a `std::unique_ptr` is `explicit`. Among other things, this means it cannot be used for [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) of the form

```
std::unique_ptr<Info> info = InfoFactory::GetInfo();
```

Instead, you can use [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization):

```
std::unique_ptr<Info> info{InfoFactory::GetInfo()};
```

Which will allow you to perform that conversion.

---

While looking at this code, however, I notice that the local variable `info` in `InfoManager::IsSomething` is shadowing the class member variable `InfoManager::info`. If you want to change an existing `std::unique_ptr` so that it's now managing a new raw pointer, you might want to use [reset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset):

```
info.reset(InfoFactory::GetInfo());
```

Comment: If you want the conversion at all. There is room for failure between `new AdvancedWindowsInfo();` and safe storage in `info` that would be solved by an end-to-end `unique_ptr` curtesy of [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique).